# British Citizen/UK resident flying to Mexico on a Mauritian passport. Do I require a visa?

Tags: visas, uk, uk-citizens, mexico, mauritius

I am wondering if anyone can shed light on travelling to Mexico on a foreign passport (Mauritian in this case) as a British citizen. I have read that as a UK resident I can.

My UK passport is at another embassy awaiting another visa and won't arrive in time before travelling.

I have checked everywhere...embassies are closed. Flight is tomorrow 10am!

Comment: If you present a Mauritius passport, you'll be treated as a Mauritian citizen. And you'll need a visa.

Answer (score 19):

To get visa-free access to Mexico as a resident of the UK, a citizen of a country whose nationals normally require visas must show a UK residence permit.  As a British citizen, you do not have a UK residence permit.  Therefore, this visa exemption will not be useful to you.

Comment: thanks guys...I believe its a VISA situation. IATA say its OK via BA but who knows if this info is correct - will call them in the AM. Appreciated people

Comment: @alvin In saying it's okay, IATA probably isn't thinking about the fact that you have no official document to prove your residence in the UK.  Nobody's going to take your word for it if you just say "I'm a UK resident" any more than they would if you just said " I'm a British citizen."